# how to change visual studio 2012 update 2 knockout js text colors?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Just updated to vs2012 update 2 but I noticed that the text colors have changed for any knockout portions in html. they have very light grey background and this makes it very hard to read. I cant find any thing specific that points to  knockout js in the fonts and colors section of the visual studio options so I havent been able to make them readable. 
does any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Is this issue affecting all JavaScript code?

Comment: no, its just in the html markup, where data-bind is defind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I installed this [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282650) and then I got the "Knockout Region" and was then able to edit the style

Comment: You don't need to download and install all the package of `ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012` just install `Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor (300KB)`. for more detail check [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537616/how-to-change-visual-studio-2012-update-2-knockout-js-text-colors/21824140#21824140).

Comment: Installation of *Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor* added nothing, but when I installed *ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012* - i was able to see *Knockout Region*

Answer (score 10):

In *Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors*, in the *Display items:*, scroll down to *Knockout region* and modify the *Item background:* color.

[image: Modify your options]

Comment: i dont have the knockout region option in the picture above.

Comment: Maybe this will help someone else -- this only works for me in files with a reference to knockout. (VS2015 vanilla build with Web Essentials installed)

Answer (score 1):

Just install [`Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor (300KB)`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05)

- It will **automatically fix the problem** for all themes. (Dark, Blue, Light)
- It is useful especially if you can't find `Knockout Region` in `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display items`.